# Rotating logo in html/javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

im trying to use html and javascript to create a rotating logo on my site.

I want it to rotate on page load, and load them randomly.

Ive tried SO MANY THINGS! that i found on google, and i cant seem to get it to work. Im trying to avoid using php to do it.

i want to be able to have the random image in a tag like below, (if possible)

```
<img src="" />
```

So, just to sum it up.

I want to use "html" and "javascript" to create a script that everytime a page is refreshed, it loads a new logo from a directory on my server.

EDIT: what i have tried

```
<script type="javascript>
    Array.prototype.random = function () { 
        return this[ parseInt( Math.random() * this.length )  ];
    }

    var myImage=[ 
        "logo1.png",
        "logo1.png",
        "logo1.png",
        "logo1.png"
    ].random()

    document.wite(myImage)
</script>
```

Comment: One moment, ill edit them in. or at least the ones i can find again :)

Comment: Why do you want to avoid php? If you want to use javascript to do it, you'll have to tell javascript all the logos that it could possibly load.

Comment: This sounds more like a request for someone to write your code for you. You should post what you've tried and the *specific* issue you ran into.

Comment: if you really don't want anything to run server side, I think you might want to make a JS array of file names, then select a random one to set as the .src of your img

Comment: I edited What i recently tried in the post.

Comment: @Ron, you understand that your images array contains 5 duplicate image files, right?

Comment: That shouldnt matter. should it? no image is showing up even with that.

Comment: @Ron: You never actually mentioned what specific issue you ran into, or what "i cant seem to get it to work" means.

Comment: The issue is nothing came up. no image. no error. it just didnt work lol

Comment: @Ron - duplicates mean the browser has to take time to figure that out.  Faster if they're not there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should avoid using document.write. Instead put an `id` attribute on the `img` tag, and retrieve it using document.getElementById. You can make it refresh at intervals using the setInterval method:

```
<img id="logo" />
<script type="text/javascript">
var logos = ["logo1.png", "logo2.png", "logo3.png"];
var currentLogoIndex = 0;
function updateLogo() {
    document.getElementById('logo').src = logos[currentLogoIndex];
    currentLogoIndex++;
    currentLogoIndex %= logos.length;
}
window.setInterval(updateLogo, 1000);
updateLogo();
</script>
```

Comment: In that case, you should use PHP.

Comment: Well, if i really have to I Can, but i would have no idea where to start on that lol.

Comment: something like: `<?php logos[rand(0, logos.length)] ?>`

Comment: could i do a <body onLoad="UpdateLogo();">

Comment: FYI probably better to include all listeners in your Javascript rather than your HTML markup, something like `document.body.onload = function() { alert("ALERT!"); }`...the point is, it's a good idea to separate script from markup as much as possible - usually all of it.

Comment: @Ron If yoou want to update on page refresh, use the concept of setting image src from this answer and the random index idea you used in your question, you should use the variable myImage as src. Add it to onLoad as Steve suggested. If you want a sinppet please ask.

Answer (score 2):

you can store the `pathes` in an array and select them by using random `index`.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var src = ['path1.jpg', 'path2.jpg', 'path3.jpg', 'path4.jpg', 'path5.jpg', 'path6.jpg', 'path7.jpg', 'path8.jpg', 'path9.jpg'];

$('img').attr('src', src[Math.floor(Math.random()*10)]) // it returns a number between 0 and 10

});
```

Answer (score 1):

You know, there is a jQuery plugin for this which utilizes CSS transformations.

http://www.zachstronaut.com/posts/2009/08/07/jquery-animate-css-rotate-scale.html

Answer (score 0):

I am Resorting to php guys.

```
<img src="/images/logo/<?php $random = rand(1,3); echo $random; ?>.png" alt="LOGO!!!!" />
```

works perfectly :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<body>
<h1>Random logo From List</h1>
<script type="javascript>
    Array.prototype.random = function () { 
        return this[ parseInt( Math.random() * this.length )  ];
    }

    var myImage=[ 
        "logo1.png",
        "logo1.png",
        "logo1.png",
        "logo1.png"
    ].random()

    document.wite("<img src='" + myImage + "' />)
</script>

<h2>Hoo just got a random logo</h2>
</body>
</html>
```

Looks like this was what you tried for:

For a bit of explanation using document.write and document.getElement:

When you write inline code like above you can use document.write, it will just add the texts just after `</h1>` like a normal "print" operation.

Once you use it after document is loaded, it clears everything and overwrites whole thing.

If you want to change the document after it is loaded, you have to edit the DOM, the document is represented as DOM after its loaded. In that case you should use different DOM manipulation functions like

```
document.getElementById('logo-image').src = myImage;
```